# Check if BitBucket repository exists via Command Line

Tags: bash, git, shell, curl, bitbucket

I know how to create a repo in BitBucket by doing this.

Let email = `john@outlook.com`, and password `123`

```
curl -k -X POST --user john@outlook.com:123 "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories" -d "name=test"
```

But how would one check if a repo exist in BitBucket programmatically ?

Comment: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/ --- there are api available. the document might help you to select the appropriate one

Comment: You really need to use the 2.0 API, because the 1.0 is deprecated and will be going away soon. https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/bitbucket-api-changes-gdpr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I get for a curl call to a public, private and non-existing repos:

Private (Status code 403):

```
> curl -k -X GET https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/padawin/some-private-repo
Forbidden
```

Non existing (Status code 404):

```
> curl -k -X GET https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/padawin/travels1
{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "Repository padawin/travels1 not found"}}
```

Public (Status code 200):

```
> curl -k -X GET https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/padawin/travels
{"scm": "git", "has_wiki": false, "last_updated": "2015-08-02T14:09:42.134", "no_forks": false, "forks_count": 0, "created_on": "2014-06-08T23:48:28.483", "owner": "padawin", "logo": "https://bytebucket.org/ravatar/%7Bb56f8d55-4821-4c89-abbc-7c1838fb68a3%7D?ts=default", "email_mailinglist": "", "is_mq": false, "size": 1194864, "read_only": false, "fork_of": null, "mq_of": null, "followers_count": 1, "state": "available", "utc_created_on": "2014-06-08 21:48:28+00:00", "website": "", "description": "", "has_issues": false, "is_fork": false, "slug": "travels", "is_private": false, "name": "travels", "language": "", "utc_last_updated": "2015-08-02 12:09:42+00:00", "no_public_forks": false, "creator": null, "resource_uri": "/api/1.0/repositories/padawin/travels"}
```

You can use the status code, given that the body is not always a valid json (`Forbidden` would have to be `"Forbidden"` to be a valid JSON).

Answer (score 1):

Using the [2.0 API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-repositories/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-get), I check in this way:

```
if curl -s -f -o /dev/null -u "${USERNAME}:${APP_PASSWORD}" "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${USERNAME}/${REPONAME}"; then
  echo "Repo exists in Bitbucket."
else
  echo "Repo either does not exist or is inaccessible in Bitbucket."
```

Access is required to the `repository:read` scope. Note that access to the `repository:admin` scope is insufficient and irrelevant for this check.